# Using getElementsByName for plain text in xhr.responseText

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing XMLHttpRequest on site that doesn't have the official API and I'm receiving HTML response in `xhr.responseText`. However, I can't do `xhr.responseText.getElementsByName("something")[0].value;` to extract a value of specific element called "something".

I can open a new window and use document.write to write `xhr.responseText` on that window and then use `window_name.getElementsByName("something")[0].value;` but I'm not going that way.

Problematic part of my code:

```
xhr.responseText.getElementsByName("something")[0].value;
```

Comment: So you're getting a whole HTML document as a response? Or just a snippet?

Comment: responseText is a string value.

Comment: @MaxArt I'm getting whole HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) in those browsers that support it:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();

var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/html");
```

Now `doc` is a `HTMLDocument` object, with `getElementsByName` and all.

Available in IE9+ and other standard browsers (IE10 for HTML documents, not available in Safari).

**Alternative**

You can [create HTML documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument) without the need of a new window/frame too:

```
doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

This should be available in IE9 and Safari too.

Comment: Beaten ! I was about to suggest this method !

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could also create a dummy element and populate its innerHTML with your Ajax responseText. Then you would have access to DOM methods on it. Set it to null when finished.

Comment: @GrégoryVorbe Yes, I was about to suggest that too, but the request returns a whole HTML document, and anyway `getElementsByName` is defined of documents only, not on elements.